# Why does cakephp not insert a field in a mysql table?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a very strange problem using **CakePHP 2.2.4**, let me explain what happen.

I have these mysql tables:

**leads**

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date       | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip         | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| service_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| location   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| message    | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**users**

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email   | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pwd     | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| role_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| active  | tinyint(4)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**profiles**

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name    | varchar(120) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| surname | varchar(120) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| company | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| vat     | varchar(60)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**addresses**

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| profile_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| address    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city       | varchar(120) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| zip_code   | char(5)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| nation     | varchar(120) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| telephone  | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mobile     | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fax        | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**roles**

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**services**

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and the follow are all the CakePhp Models I use (with the associations):

**Lead.php**

```
class Lead extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Lead';

    /* Relazioni */      
    public $belongsTo = array('User', 'Service');
}
```

**User.php**

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'User';

    /* Relazioni */
    public $hasOne = 'Profile';

    public $belongsTo = 'Role';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Lead' => array(
            'className' => 'Lead'
        )
    );  

}
```

**Profile.php**

```
class Profile extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Profile';

    /* Relazioni */
    public $belongsTo = 'User';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Address' => array(
            'className' => 'Address'
        )
    );  

}
```

**Address.php**

```
class Address extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Address';

    /* Relazioni */        
    public $belongsTo = 'Profile';

}
```

**Service.php**

```
class Service extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Service';

}
```

I have a form that must to be saves in more than one mysql table.

This is the code i use to draft the FORM:

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
                            'inputDefaults' => array(
                                'error' => false
                            )
                        )
                ); //create(false) per il form senza il modello

echo $this->Form->input('User.Profile.name', array(
                            'label' => array(   
                                'class' => 'name-form',                                                                                                                                         
                                'text'  => 'Nome:'                                                                      
                            ),                                                              
                            'style' => 'width:238px;',
                            'div'   => 'field'
                        )
               );                               

echo $this->Form->input('User.Profile.surname', array(
                            'label' => array(   
                                'class' => 'name-form',                                                                                                                                         
                                'text'  => 'Cognome:'                                                                       
                            ),                                                              
                            'style' => 'width:238px;',
                            'div'   => 'field'
                        )
               );                                   

?>

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php

echo $this->Form->input('User.email', array(
                            'label' => array(                                                                       
                                'class' => 'name-form',
                                'text'  => 'Email:'
                            ),                                                              
                            'div'   => 'field', 
                            'class' => 'input-xlarge'
                        )
               );

echo $this->Form->input('User.Profile.Address.telephone', array(
                            'label' => array(   
                                'class' => 'name-form',                                                                                                                                         
                                'text'  => 'Telefono:'                                                                      
                            ),                                                          
                            'div'   => 'field'
                        )
               );                          
?>

<div class="clear"></div>


<?php                      

echo $this->Form->input('Lead.service_id',
                    array(
                        'label' => array(                                                                       
                            'class' => 'name-form',
                            'text'  => 'Servizio richiesto:'
                        ),                                                              
                        'div'   => 'field',
                        'type'  => 'select',                                                                
                        'options' => $services                                      
                    )
);                              

echo $this->Form->input('Lead.location', array(
                            'label' => array(                                                                       
                                'class' => 'name-form',
                                'text'  => 'Vicino a:'
                            ),                                                              
                            'div'   => 'field', 
                            'class' => 'input-xlarge'
                        )
               );                               

?>

<div class="clear"></div>


<?php

echo $this->Form->input('Lead.message', array(
                            'label' => array(                                                                       
                                'class' => 'message-form',
                                'text'  => 'Richiesta:'
                            ),                                                              
                            'div'   => 'field', 
                            'class' => 'form-field',
                            'type'  => 'textarea'
                        )
               );                                                               

echo $this->Form->button('Invia Richiesta', array(
                                        'type'  => 'submit',
                                        'class' => 'submit-btn less-margin'
                                    )
                );

echo $this->Form->end();

?>
```

And this is the action of the controller(PagesController) that saves the data:

```
public function home() 
{       
   if ($this->request->is('post'))
   {
    $this->loadModel('Lead');

    $this->request->data['Lead']['ip']   = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $this->request->data['Lead']['date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
    $this->request->data['User']['role_id'] = 3;    

    $this->Lead->set($this->request->data);

    debug($this->request->data);

    if ($this->Lead->validates()) 
    {
        // Dati nel modulo corretti
        debug($this->Lead->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true)));
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Errore nella validazione
        $this->Session->setFlash('Completare correttamente il form', 'default', array('class' => 'errore'), 'lead');

        $errors = $this->Lead->validationErrors;                
        debug($errors);
    }   
}

$this->loadModel('Service');

$this->set('services', $this->Service->find('list'));               

}
```

And this is the output generated from the FORM:

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'Profile' => array(
            'name' => 'The Name',
            'surname' => 'The Surname',
            'Address' => array(
                'telephone' => 'The Telephone'
            )
        ),
        'email' => 'the@email.com',
        'role_id' => (int) 3
    ),
    'Lead' => array(
        'service_id' => '1',
        'location' => 'The location',
        'message' => 'This is the request',
        'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
        'date' => '2013-01-01 08:07:42'
    )
)
```

**PROBLEM:**

All work correctly, except one thing... `saveAll()` saves all the data correctly (in each model), but in the addresses table I only see that CakePhp insert **profile_id**, only this field, but as you can see in the array generated from the FORM, I also have the telephone!

Why does cakephp not also insert the **telephone** field?

Thank you

Comment: You need to view http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html?highlight=saveall#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array. Specifically the part that says: it is important to realize that saving model data should always be done by the corresponding CakePHP model

Comment: @TimJoyce pardon, i do not getting you... are you telling to me that if I have 3 groups of fields (for group I mean...field related to different models), do I have to do Model1->save() ... Model2->save() --- Model3->save() again and again ? do you mean it ?

Comment: Yes, this example here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html?highlight=saveall#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto should set you on the right path to saving related model data.

Comment: @TimJoyce before I have followed this method, but if i have to use ->save() for each Model, when do I need to use saveAll() ?

Comment: @TimJoyce and again...is this not too redundant? because at the moment all works good, except (telephone) but cakephp write in addresses table because i see the correct profile_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making up code, hence it does not work.

Nowhere in the cake docs does it say to use the following code:

## Incorrect

```
$this->Form->input('User.Profile.surname');
$this->Form->input('User.Profile.Address.telephone');
```

You can not just string words together and hope for the best. You can either use:

## Correct

```
$this->Form->input('field');
$this->Form->input('Model.field');
$this->Form->input('Model.n.field');
```

There are no other valid ways to enter fields.

Instead of making things up, read the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)

```
$this->Form->input('Profile.surname');
```

Comment: @dogmatic69 I do not understand what "format" is correct. I already use format like: 'User.Profile.Address.telephone' is this wrong ?

Comment: @Dail Yes, that's his point. It should be just `Address.telephone` instead. The relations will handle the rest.

Comment: @Oldskool 'Address.telephone' does not work. I tried it instead of 'User.Profile.Address.telephone'....if i do that CakePHP does also not save profile_id in the addresses table

Answer (score 0):

"The [saveAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html?highlight=saveall#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array) function is just a wrapper around the saveMany and saveAssociated methods."

Try using `saveAssociated` instead so that you are forcing the `saveAssociated` method. Still pass the `array('deep'=>true);`. The way your output is formatted, it may be trying to automatically use `saveMany`.

Also, if you have validation on your `telephone` field in your model, it will fail since you have a string in there that does not contain any numbers. `The Telephone`. Or, you can pass the option of `'validate' => false`.